# Binomial sum gives $4^n$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I was looking at this question:[Swapping the $i$th largest card between $2$ hands of cards](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591461/swapping-the-ith-largest-card-between-2-hands-of-cards/1591899#1591899)
and WolframAlpha gave me this result.

Why is it so? $$\sum_{k=0}^n{2k\choose k}{2n-2k\choose n-k}=4^n?$$

Comment: This may be relevant:https://mikespivey.wordpress.com/2012/05/21/altconvcentralbinom2/

Comment: this is very nice http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF03026737#page-2

Comment: Also see http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/q2h1128128p5227047 for a cool 'word' argument.

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/37971/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Convolution of the series
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{1-4x}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2n}{n}x^n
$$
gives
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}x^n
&=\frac1{\sqrt{1-4x}}\frac1{\sqrt{1-4x}}\\
&=\frac1{1-4x}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty4^nx^n
\end{align}
$$
Equating coefficients of $x^n$ gives
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}=4^n
$$